# Extracting certain value from MongoDB using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo database including the following collection:

```
"
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "12345"
  },
  "id": "333555",
  "token": [
    {
      "access_token": "ac_33bc",
      "expires_in": 3737,
      "token_type": "bearer",
      "expires_at": {
        "$date": "2021-07-02T13:37:28.123Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the next python script I'm trying to return and print only the access_token but can't figure out how to do so. I've tried various methods which none of the worked.I've given the "id" as a parameter

```
def con_mongo():
    try:
        client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb:localhost")
        #DB name
        db = client["db1"]
        #Collection
        coll = db["coll1"]

   #1st method
        x = coll.find({"id":"333555"},{"token":"access_token"})
        for data in x:
            print(x)

   #2nd method
        x= coll.find({"id":"333555"})
        tok=x.distinct("access_token")
        #print(x[0])
        for data in tok:
            print(data)
    except Exception:
        logging.info(Exception)
```

It doesn't work this way, although if I replace (or remove) the "access_token" with simply "token" it works but I get back all the informations included in the field "token" where I only need the value of the "access_token".

Comment: Couldn't you get all `token` information and from that extract `access_token`?

Comment: I can, I tried extracting the `access_token` as an array but didn't work

Comment: Try using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator.

Comment: Tried using it as such `x = coll.find({"id":"333555"},{ "token": { "$elemMatch": { "token": { "access_token":1} } } } )
        for data in x:
            print(data)`. Didn't work but I think I am getting closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `access_token` is an array element, you need to qualify it's name with the name of the array, to properly access its value.

Actually you can first extract the whole document and get the desired value through simple list and dict indexing.

So, assuming you are retrieving many documents with that same `id`:

```
x = [doc["token"][0]["access_token"] for doc in coll.find({"id":"333555"})]
```

The above, comprehensively creates a list with the `access_tokens` of all the documents matching the given `id`.

If you just need the first (and maybe only) occurrence of a document with that `id`, you can use `find_one()` instead:

```
x = coll.find_one({"id":"333555"})["token"][0]["access_token"]
# returns ac_33bc
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation , I was looking only through token[0] and not further , so this gave me the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`token` is a list so you have to reference the list element, e.g.

```
x = coll.find({"id":"333555"},{"token.access_token"})
for data in x:
    print(data.get('token')[0].get('access_token'))
```

prints:

```
ac_33bc
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , it did indeed work this way I just had to dig through more into the list hierarchy